# String date current date/time?

Tags: php, datetime

I am using  `$date = date("D M d, Y G:i");`.

When I echo `$date`, it shows the correct date/time. Now I need this as an string.

I have tried `string($date)`; but nothing happens here. And

```
$today = strtotime($date);
```

here I get weird numbers..

I need a string so I can put `$today` in a message.

What is the correct method for this?

Comment: `date()` function returns `string` what are you looking for please elaborate? It is already a string

Comment: lol you echo it and it is correct, so leave it alone!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The [**`date()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function already returns a string.

Doing this :

```
$date = date("D M d, Y G:i");
```

You'll have the current date in the `$date` variable, as a string -- **no need for any additional operation**.

Answer (score 4):

If you like working with objects you can do this:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
echo $date->format('D M d, Y G:i');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `$date` variable is a string, there's no need for any conversion.

You can have a look at the documentation: http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. The return value of the `date()` function is string.

The strange numbers you see when you call `strtotime()` is the Unix timestamp which represents the number of seconds elapsed since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You're already getting a string. $date can be used like any string now.

`strtotime()` actually gives you the number of seconds in time like unix

Comment: ah now i am getting it. 
it display now almost correctly
Thu Mar 03, 2011 13:09 
now just need to get +1 hour gmt then i am done :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = 'Today is '.date("D M d, Y G:i", time());
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to:

```
$today = strtotime($date);
```

Those numbers are the current timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1st 1970).
You can use this as a second parameter in the date function to change the date to whatever you want.

```
$newDate = date("D M d, Y G:i", $timeStamp);
```