# timestamp(int) to date(string) in php

Tags: php, datetime

This my code to generate current date.

```
$now= Time();
$dt=date("d", strtotime($now));
echo $dt;
```

It outputs `01` as `d-m-Y` outputs `01-01-1970` instead of current date.

`$dt` is string and `$now` is integer type. What should I do to get correct date and get it as integer type.

Comment: Try with `echo (int) $dt`. It force the variable to be an integer

Comment: [`Time()`  is already your current Date and Time as int, so `strtotime` is not required which is why it returns the wrong date.](https://eval.in/192641) Duplicate of [String date current date/time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180730/string-date-current-date-time)

Comment: what? `echo date('d');` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert `time()` to `strtotime()`. `strtotime()` accepts date as string. `time()` will return the current time in integer only.

Try with

```
$date = date('d', time());
```

Comment: And the default value for `date`'s second argument is... `time()`. So you can leave that out too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to get current date

```
$dt=date("d-m-Y", strtotime('today')); //dd-mm-yyyy
echo $dt;
```

OR

```
$current_date_in_int = Time(); 
$current_date_in_string = date('d-m-Y', $current_date_in_int); //dd-mm-yyyy
echo $current_date_in_string;
```